# How can I formatt a value in v-for inside a el-option in element ui

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I need formatt to decimal value the value in label(item.value) inside a v-for.

Here is my code:

```
<el-form-item :label="label" :required="required" prop="Jan">
      <el-select v-model="Jan" clearable filterable placeholder="Selecione" :multiple="multiple" :disabled="disabled" :loading="loading" @change="onChange">
        <el-option
          v-for="item in orcindex"
          :key="item.id"
          :label="item.name + ' - ' + item.value + '%'"
          :value="item.id"
        />
      </el-select>
    </el-form-item>
```

I already have a function to formatt:

import { numberFormat } from '@/utils/cells-format'

```
 methods: {
    cellValueRenderer(cellValue) {
      var value = numberFormat(cellValue, 'decimal')
      return value
    }
 }
```

So how can I use this function to formatt the value in v-for? (Im new in vuejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the function.

```
<el-option
      v-for="item in orcindex"
      :key="item.id"
      :label="item.name + ' - ' + cellValueRenderer(item.value) + '%'"
      :value="item.id"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use slots to have a custom label

```
<el-form-item :label="label" :required="required" prop="Jan">
      <el-select v-model="Jan" clearable filterable placeholder="Selecione" :multiple="multiple" :disabled="disabled" :loading="loading" @change="onChange">
        <el-option
          v-for="item in orcindex"
          :key="item.id"
          :value="item.id"
        >
        <span>{{ cellValueRenderer(item.label) }}</span>
        </el-option>
      </el-select>
    </el-form-item>
```